# Changing width of notebook tab in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to change width of notebooks tabs in tkinter without just entering `space` in the name of the tab? I have tried to put width but I didnt succeed.
Is there any option like `tabwidht` or something like that, so that I can have fixed size of tab?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='wn',width=80)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')

f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='red', width=200, height=200)
f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='blue', width=200, height=200)

notebook.add(f1, text="frame 1")
notebook.add(f2, text="frame 2 longer")

notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no option to set the tab size of the ttk.Notebook.

Answer (score 4):

Use string formatting, when defining the text of your tabs:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='red', width=200, height=200)
f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='blue', width=200, height=200)

notebook.add(f1, text=f'{"frame 1": ^20s}')
notebook.add(f2, text=f'{"frame 2 longer": ^20s}')

notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
root.mainloop()
```

Instead of '20' use a size of your choice.
Be careful to use the correct quote characters:

```
f'{"something": ^20s}'
```

or the other way round:

```
f"{'something': ^20s}"
```

Comment: As an afterthought: Of course, this is just another way to add space to the text, so it doesn't quite answer your question. But then: it works.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this works/what you're doing? I'm a bit lost...

Comment: notebook treats the whole string (including trailing spaces) passed in as the title of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ttk custom style to configure the size:

```
import tkinter, tkinter.ttk

#Setup a custom style
notebookStyle = ttk.Style()
notebookStyle.configure('Custom.TNotebook.Tab', padding=[30,4])
            
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(parent, style = "Custom.TNotebook")
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149575/13867483).